# Enthought Canopy Setup Wizard ended prematurely

Tags: enthought

Installing Canopy 2.1.9 for Windows 64-bit on Windows 10, and the installer fails immediately after clicking the Install button, with the message "Enthought Canopy (64-bit) Setup Wizard ended prematurely because of an error."  Same result using 2.1.8.  Same result using the run-as-administrator command line msiexec instructions, same result running the installer as administrator, same result installing for current user or all users.

Answer (score 0):

Enthought support here. Sounds like there's something unusual about your current system status. Most likely would be interference from a 3rd-party anti-virus program, or similar. If temporarily disabling that doesn't help, then please run `msiexec /Lv*x canopy-msi.log ... etc...`, then zip and send the resulting log, with a link to this SO question, to support@enthought.com. We'll look at it as time permits, though we do not have the bandwidth to help you debug your system setup.